# Autojump in 12.04 doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, apt, bash, repository

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autojump

I installed with apt-get, checked out the man page and added 
`. /usr/share/autojump/autojump.sh` to my .bashrc, like it says. When I `cd` around the filesystem, nothing gets added to `~/.local/share/autojump`. I then tried adding `. /usr/share/autojump/autojump.bash`, but that didn't work either.

`autojump -a ~/Dropbox` properly creates a file `~/.local/share/autojump/autojump.txt`, but running `j Drop < TAB >` doesn't autocomplete to `j ~/Dropbox/` as it should. However, `j < TAB >` does autocomplete to `j ~/Dropbox`.

I know my bash-completion is working since it works for git, dd, and others.

I know there's a newer version in the repositories set for Quantal. Perhaps that would work? I don't know how to install that version though. I've used autojump with mac homebrew (and it installed without any issue), so I know there is missing functionality.

In general I'm really annoyed that I can't get this working...I've spent hours on it! Needless to say, help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You might want to say how you installed autojump, whether it was via the .deb package. It's not clear if it's installed correctly.

Comment: I thought my first sentence made that clear -- I installed with `sudo apt-get install autojump`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As posted in https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/issues/148 )

autojump silently fails if PROMPT_COMMAND has been overwritten:

If in your .bashrc you have `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n;"`

PROMPT_COMMAND - which autojump requires -  will fail to be set properly.

Instead do: `export PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"; history -a; history -n;"`

Comment: Gah, that sounds like a bug for the original author.

Comment: This worked for me all the way in 2023.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I have a handle on how this works.

You'll probably want to add the following to your .bashrc:

```
source /usr/share/autojump/autojump.bash
```

This should do what you're expecting it to do.

Also, what does jumpstat bring back?

Comment: I installed the newest version autojump (v20) from here http://packages.debian.org/sid/autojump
but still nothing is added to the ~/.local/share/autojump/autojump.txt file. I even set $XDG_DATA_HOME to ~/.local/share

Comment: I also tried sourcing the autojump.bash script like you say and it doesn't do anything different. 
jumpstat only reports directories I've added manually: 1.0: /home/hashem/temp
1.0: /home/hashem/Dropbox/
Total key weight: 2. Number of stored paths: 2